# Writing to databse with AWS Lambda error - Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Network Error

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I am querying API, storing it to a pandas dataframe, transforming it and then writing it to a AWS Redshift database. On my local machine there are no issues and everything works fine. When I placed the code in AWS Lambda, with all the required packages I get this error:

```
Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Network Error
```

I've read that it may be due to the limits of how many rows it can write to a database, then I tried to write only 1 row to the database but still got the same error.

My code where I write looks like this:

```
conn = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@redshifteu-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/dev')
result.to_sql('table_1', conn, index=False, if_exists='replace', schema='schema')
```

I am using pandas `to_sql` method and `sqlalchemy`. How can I write my dataframe to a Redshift database with AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you may need [`psycopg2`](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/) in order to connect to Redshift through SQLAlchemy:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

---

Now another possibility could be that you are essentially exceeding the rate [limit of S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/optimizing-performance.html).

---

If the above doesn't work and you are confident that the rate limit is not exceeded, you can give [`pandas_redshift`](https://github.com/agawronski/pandas_redshift) a go:

```
# pip install pandas-redshift
import pandas_redshift as pr


pr.connect_to_redshift(
    dbname='dev', host='redshifteu-west-1.redshift.amazonaws.com', 
    port=5439, user='user', password='password'
)

pr.connect_to_s3(
   aws_access_key_id='aws_access_key_id',
   aws_secret_access_key='aws_secret_access_key',
   bucket='bucket_name',
   subdirectory='subdirectory'
)

pr.pandas_to_redshift(data_frame=result, redshift_table_name='table_1')
```

Comment: I have psycopg2 installed specially for aws servers from a github I've found. Thanks, will try your method.

Comment: Do I need the connect_to_s3 part if I only want to write to redshift?

Comment: Still getting the same issue - Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: Network Error

Comment: @JonasPalačionis How about the limit?

Comment: But I am not using S3 ( as I understand ), I only use AWS lambda to query an API and write those pandas dataframes to a Redshift. I assume if the code works fine on my local machine it should work on lambda as well.

Comment: I am not sure what I should place as a subdirectory and if bucket should remain `<bucket>` or should I name the directory I wish to place the life, like the name of the bucket as `name_of_the_bucket`?

Comment: yes you should use 'name_of_the_bucket', subdirectory is optional. Note that you cannot write data to Redshift without s3.